# How to properly use javascript-links for users without js

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hyperlink, unobtrusive-javascript

I hope I'm not creating a duplicate here, but I just don't really know what to look for/didn't find anything useful yet.

I got several links (`<a>`) on my page that trigger the jquery click() handler, which will load a new page into a div without reload. To make those links available to non-javascript users, I want to link them to the same page (that's why I'm using s and not just any div/span/button). Propblem with that is that the script will reload anyway, so you can say jaavascript is overwritten.

So how do I prevent the browser using the link as a link with javascript? Or what's the correct solution to allow non-javascript users to be able to use the site properly as well ?

The only solution I could come up with by myself is just using buttons, but I find that quite bulky as I have to use a form although I only submit 1 variable via `GET` which is only specified in the link itself. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're doing, returning `false` will work as others have answered, but beware of overusing `return false;` in jQuery event handlers.

You would probably be better served by calling `preventDefault()` to stop the click action only. It will prevent the link from being followed, but not stop any other handlers that may be attached. See [jQuery events: stop misusing return false](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) for a detailed explanation.

example:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    // your custom code
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thought already my question was covered with return false; but your answer is even more useful! preventDefault() is what I really want! Propably prevented me from scratching my head later on, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

If you `return false` to the click event handler, it will not follow through with the default action, which in your case would be to follow the link to the new page...

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    // process your event...
    return false;
});
```

Then, if javascript is disabled, it will follow the `<a>` tag to the new `href` as expected.

Comment: thanks for that, exactly what I needed! icktoofay was faster though, so I can only upvote you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you're using jQuery, return `false` in the event handler.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery gives you several ways to deal with this problem.

```
$('.some-link').click(function(event) {
   //just prevent browsers default behavior
   event.preventDefault();
   //stop calling all other handlers, including live
   event.stopPropagation();
   //stop calling all handlers listening to the same dom node
   event.stopImmediatePropagation()

   //do all of the above
   return false;
)}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "a" ).click( function() {
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

This will prevent the event (ie the click) from changing the page but it will also prevent you from chaining methods. Method chaining looks like this:

```
$( "a" ).click( function(){} ).css( 'color', 'red' );
```

The click will be cancelled but the css ALSO won't execute.

Using .preventDefault() is pretty standard and won't cause this issue.

```
$( "a" ).click( function( event ) {
    // ...
    event.preventDefault();
});
```