# Issue with Show/Hide function in jQuery. Jumps to top of document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I have 2 basic Show / Hide links on my website which work great.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codylindley.com/blogstuff/js/jquery/jquery-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input.buttonAsize").click(function(){ alert($("div.contentToChange").find("p").size()); });
    $("a.codeButtonA").click(function(){$("pre.codeA").toggle()});

    $("input.buttonBsize").click(function(){ alert($("div.contentToChange").find("p").size()); });
    $("a.codeButtonB").click(function(){$("pre.codeB").toggle()});

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
pre {
background: white;
overflow: auto;
display:none;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <a href="#" class="codeButtonA">Show / Hide</a>
    <pre class="codeA">
    test message 1
    </pre>

<div style="background:green;margin-top:1000px">
    <a href="#" class="codeButtonB">Show / Hide</a>
    <pre class="codeB">
    test message 2
    </pre>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, when I click the 2nd link at the foot of the page it **does** open the `<pre>` tag , but then jumps to the top of the page. Is there a way to stop this from then jumping to the top of the page when I click it?

I'd prefer if it just showed the box and never jumped to the top.

Many thanks for any help with this.

Comment: add **return false** to that functions.

Comment: remember that it's good practice to pick the best answer, so other users can find the solution faster too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or remove `href="#"` from the `<A>` tags

Comment: Wow, that was simple :) I also added `a:hover {cursor:pointer}` to my CSS so users still know it's a "clicker". Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input.buttonAsize").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($("div.contentToChange").find("p").size());
});

$("a.codeButtonA").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("pre.codeA").toggle();
});

$("input.buttonBsize").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($("div.contentToChange").find("p").size());
});

$("a.codeButtonB").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("pre.codeB").toggle()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As I just learned from [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788534/how-to-properly-use-javascript-links-for-users-without-js), where I had more or less the same problem, `return false;` is the simple minded solution. It works, but it can also prevent other code from running. The explanation is to find here in this [wonderful tutorial](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/).

Most likely you want to use something like

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
    // your custom code
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

It basically stops/prevents the browser to do the default action, which is linking to itself when using `#` as `href`. Return false also stops following scripts from working if in the same handler. But the tutorial explains this way better :)

In your case it would be

```
$("a.codeButtonB").click(function(event){
    $("pre.codeB").toggle();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

That's propably the best solution if you want to use  links. Using buttons would be the other solution, but that restricts you in some ways. Plus, you could (read:should) keep the a and give it a real href to the content you want to display, that way it will still work when javascript is disabled on the client.

Answer (score 2):

Add `return: false;` to your `click` events.

Comment: Thank you for this, garvey!! Will try in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `a` tags for things that are not really links. Use the `button` tag.

Answer (score 0):

add `return false` to both the functions.